# Finding the value of this limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x^4-x^4\cos x^4+x^{20}}{x^4(e^{2x^4}-1-2x^4)}$$

The answer is given to be $1$. Can someone give any hint/s related to this problem?

More importantly, why am I not able to get the answer by simply  using L hopital's rule and by basic substitution of trigonometric and exponential limits?

Any kind of help would be appreciated. I gave the problem simply as an example to reflect the above confusion.

**EDIT**: Even though tag says so, you are still allowed to use l hospital's rule to help evaluate the limit. 
The question is edited now. It is e^(2x^4) in denominator.

Again, thanks a lot for taking your time to reply to my doubt.

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: Are you saying that you are not allowed to use L'Hopital, or that when you try to use it you do not get an answer?

Comment: Check that my edit is what you intended.

Comment: The limit is not $1$.

Comment: is it $\sin(x^4)$ or $(\sin(x))^4$?

Comment: Do you mind adding parentheses to the expression ?

Comment: According to Wolfram the limit is $0$

Comment: the searched Limit is $0$

Comment: @Idris could you take a look at my answer? I also got the answer to be $0$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton You are allowed to use it, but in my case, I don't know when. It is very confusing, and I get zero as the answer.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It is Sine of x^4, and not sinx the whole power 4. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: @RoryDaulton It is actually e^(2x^4) in the denominator, and not e^(2x). Will this change your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't yet use Taylor expansions, you can still use l'Hôpital with some simplifications to begin with.

### Edited question

For the question where $e^{2x^4}$ is in the denominator instead of $e^{2x}$, the first step to do is the substitution $t=\sqrt[4]{x}$, noting that the function is even; so surely
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)
$$
as soon as one of them exists. The limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t+t^5}{t(e^{2t}-1-2t)}
$$

We can look for $k$ such that
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{e^{2t}-1-2t}{t^k}
$$
exists, finite and nonzero: with l'Hôpital
$$
=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{2e^{2t}-2}{kt^{k-1}}
=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{4e^{2t}}{k(k-1)t^{k-2}}
$$
which is $2$ as soon as $k=2$. So the original limit can be written
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t+t^5}{2t^3}
\frac{2t^2}{e^{2t}-1-2t}
$$
and the second factor can be disregarded, so the limit to compute is
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\frac{\sin t-t\cos t}{2t^3}+t^2\right)
$$
and the second summand can be disregarded. With l'Hôpital on the first summand,
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t}{2t^3}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\cos t-\cos t+t\sin t}{6t^2}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin t}{6t}=\frac{1}{6}
$$

With Taylor expansions available,
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t+t^5}{t(e^{2t}-1-2t)}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t+t^5}{t(1+2t+4t^2/2!+o(t^3)-1-2t)}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t+t^5}{2t^3+o(t^4)}
$$
so we need to stop Taylor expansion at the $t^3$ terms in the numerator:
$$
\sin t-t\cos t+t^5=t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+o(t^4)-
t\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2!}+o(t^4)\right)+t^5=
\frac{1}{3}t^3+o(t^4)
$$
and so we have
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{3}t^3+o(t^4)}{2t^3+o(t^4)}=\frac{1}{6}
$$

### Original question

Let's look if we can find $k$ such that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1-2x^4}{x^k}
$$
is finite and non zero. We can proceed supposing that we have an indeterminate form $0/0$ until the derivative of the denominator becomes constant, so we have 
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1-2x^4}{x^k}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2e^{2x}-8x^3}{kx^{k-1}}
$$
which is non zero as soon as $k=1$; so we conclude that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1-2x^4}{x}=2
$$
and we can transform the original limit into
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}
\frac{\sin x^4-x^4\cos x^4+x^{20}}{2x^5}
\frac{2x}{(e^{2x}-1-2x^4)}
$$
The second factor can then be disregarded, because its limit is $1$. So we're left with
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}
\left(\frac{\sin x^4-x^4\cos x^4}{2x^5}+\frac{x^{15}}{2}\right)
$$
and the second summand has limit $0$, so we can disregard it. Now we have something more manageable:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}
\frac{\sin x^4-x^4\cos x^4}{2x^5}
$$
where we can apply the substitution $t=\sqrt[4]{x}$ (when $x>0$), so let first compute the limit from the right:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin x^4-x^4\cos x^4}{2x^5}=
\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t}{2t^{5/4}}\overset{\mathrm{(H)}}{=}
\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\cos t-\cos t+t\sin t}{(5/2)t^{1/4}}=0
$$
For the limit from the left apply the substitution $t=\sqrt[4]{-x}$, and the result is $0$ as well.

So you can end up by saying
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x^4-x^4\cos x^4+x^{20}}{x^4(e^{2x}-1-2x^4)}=0
$$

Comment: The question was not edited correctly. I have edited it again. So now, how can you correctly use l hospital's rule on the the second limit? (the limit involving x^k)

Comment: @user232216 Edited

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks a lot for your solutions. But one more thing. Can you tell me WHEN I can use l hopital's rule for evaluating these kind of limits? You can also choose to use it immediately from the start, as it is 0/0 form. How can I apply it effectively?

Comment: @user232216 As you see, the exercise was really about the transformed limit, then they changed $t$ into $x^4$, making direct usage of l'Hôpital a nightmare: the denominator essentially has degree $3$ in $t$, making for three applications of l'Hôpital; with the transformation it becomes degree $12$ in $x$, with as many applications of the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Divide numerator and denominator by $x^4$, giving you

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x^4}{x^4}-\cos x^4+x^{16}}{e^{2x^4}-1-2x^4}$$

Now expand the sine, cosine, and exponential into power series (Maclaurin series) with as many terms as needed.

Comment: "Expand into power series as many terms as needed" is exactly the same as using l'Hopital. Which, according to the tags, is not what the asker is after.

Comment: @Arthur. May I say that I do not agree ? Just looking at the expansion of $e^{2x}-1-2x^4$ basically tells how many terms you need to use for the numerator (whatever it could be).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici But accessing the second degree term of the Taylor series of the numerator and the denominator and comparing them is _exactly_ what you do if you use l'Hopital twice.

Comment: @Arthur. I must confess that I agree !! Moreover, after the edit of the question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use taylor series (a lot easier than L'Hopital's):

We have the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x^4-x^4\cos x^4+x^{20}}{x^4(e^{2x}-1-2x^4)}$$
Using taylor series:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x^4-x^4\cos x^4+x^{20}}{x^4(e^{2x}-1-2x^4)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x^4-\frac{(x^4)^3}{3!} + \frac{(x^4)^5}{5!} - \ldots\right)-x^4\left(1-\frac{(x^4)^2}{2!} + \frac{(x^4)^4}{4!} - \ldots\right)+x^{20}}{x^4\left(\left(1 + 2x + \frac{(2x)^2}{2} + \frac{(2x)^3}{6} + \ldots\right) +-1-2x^4\right)}= \frac{\frac{x^{12}}{12} + \ldots}{2x^5 + \ldots + \frac{256x^{12}}{40320} + \ldots} = 0$$

If you notice, our leading coefficient for the numerator is $x^{12}$ and for the denominator is $x^5$.

I don't believe the answer is $1$. Therefore, the answer is $0$. Comment if you have questions.

Comment: It is actually e^(2x^4) in the denominator, and not e^(2x). Can you try it now? I am getting zero as my final result